# Unmanaged C++ class in C#

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, managed

Can I instantiate and "work with" an unmanaged C++ class from C# code (say, using DllImport and such)?

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, you can use [COM interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to work with C++. This won't work on Linux/Mac OS X, however.

Another alternative is to expose a C wrapper around the C++ class (extern "C" in C++). This is necessary because DllImport expects a C ABI.

Edit: and a third alternative is [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), i.e. compile your C++ code for .Net. This is also a Windows-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SWIG. It works with Mono on Linux and Mac.

It generates a set of C functions which expose the C++ class, and generates a C# class that calls them with DllImport.

It allows inheriting C++ classes in C#, and with Directors feature C++ code can call back virtual methods overridden in C#.